# How to call Spring Bean method from JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a method in Spring Bean which returns JdbcTemplate as shown below.

```
     @Configuration
     public class Mybean {   
         JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;   
         @Bean
         @Autowired
         public JdbcTemplate getJDBC(DataSource dataSource){
             this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);    
             return jdbcTemplate;
         }    
     }
```

And I called this bean from my JSP as shown below.

```
 <%                    
  new Mybeans().jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select *  from discounts");
 %>
```

But this is throwing error NullPointerException.

Is this right way to do? Please bear me if I am wrong as I am completely new to springs.

I did not declared Bean(Mybean) in Spring XML file, am I have to do that, why?

Comment: I think you have to declare it in spring context xml file

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do declare properties to bean in XML for Mybean?

Comment: Don't call the class from Jsp. Create a [controller to query for data](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm), put it in a ModelAndView object and use this in the Jsp.

Comment: @Stefan Yes you are right. Cannot we call a Bean to do some operations.

Comment: You can but you shouldn't... Your view should be your view, which renders a model which is prepared by a controller. Basically you don't want to put java code in your jsp.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you tell me how to access simple spring bean from a JSP, any tutorial is also fine.

Comment: No as that would be teaching you bad programming practices. You shouldn't be calling beans from a JSP.